# Sort MySQL result to make results with a certain value in either of two columns display last

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say this is a table named `fixtures`:

```
id | team1 | team2
1  | 25    | 40
2  | 10    | 0
3  | 13    | 8
4  | 0     | 18
5  | 32    | 12
```

I need to sort the result in such a way that the rows where `team1` is 0 OR `team2` is 0 end up last. The order of the other rows doesn't matter, as long as they all come before the ones with at least one 0. The order of the 0 rows relative to one another doesn't matter either. So, for the example above, the order of output row IDs should be something like:

```
1, 3, 5, 2, 4
```

I know I could do this in PHP after getting all the results, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it in a query.

Note: all the other values (apart from 0) can only be positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    TableName
ORDER   BY (LEAST(team1, team2) = 0), ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3da76/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╗
║ ID ║
╠════╣
║  1 ║
║  3 ║
║  5 ║
║  2 ║
║  4 ║
╚════╝
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Never came across `LEAST` before. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes.